# Computing congruence subgroups indeces in $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-forms

Let $N$ be an integer, it is easy compute the indices in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of the congruence subgroups $\Gamma(N),\Gamma_1(N),\Gamma_0(N)$.

My question is: can I compute the indices $$[\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z}):\bar{ \Gamma}(N)],[\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z}):\bar{ \Gamma}_1(N)],[\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z}):\bar{ \Gamma}_0(N)]$$

just knowing their indices in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Can you please remind us what $\bar\Gamma(N)$ etc. are?

Comment: Yes, we can. Everything is listed [here](http://www.uncg.edu/mat/faculty/pauli/congruence/) according to the genus, including the index.

Comment: $\overline{\Gamma} = \Gamma \cap PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ ? @DietrichBurde And the congruence subgroups are defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup#Principal_congruence_subgroups

Comment: Thank you for the link, I knew it. However, I would like to understand the reasonament behind it. Only looking the table is not clear to me.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the table alone is difficult. On the other hand, if you do a search on the web, you will find many helpful articles.

Answer (score 4):

If $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_(\Bbb Z)$ and
$\bar G$ is a the image of $G$ in $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\Bbb Z)$, then
$$|\mathrm{PSL}_2(\Bbb Z):\bar G|=|\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z):\pm G|.$$
This is either $|\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z):G|$ or $\frac12|\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z):G|$ according whether or not $-I\in G$.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly the group index is given as follows:

$$
[PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma (m)]=\frac{m^3}{2}\prod_{p\mid m}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}, \right),\; m\ge 3
$$

$$
[PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma_1 (m)]=\frac{m^2}{2}\prod_{p\mid m}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}, \right),\; m\ge 3
$$

$$
[PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma_0 (m)]=m\prod_{p\mid m}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}, \right),\; m\ge 1.
$$

Here
$$
\Gamma (m) = \{A \in PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \mid A\equiv \pm I \bmod m\}/\{\pm I\}.
$$